# neo4j java query huge slow down with DB > 32G

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

I am testing a java query on different size dataset, 100 Million to 1 Billion edges (10 edges per vertex). 
The query does not return much data, 10 to 20 vertices with corresponding edges but it need to scan the whole dataset.

I can see a big performances degradation when the database size is bigger than 32 Gigs.
I changed the java heap size to 96G and played with the garbage collector options (retain -XX:+UseG1GC as the most improving option) 
to get a better outcome but I still get big dip in performances:

100M edge, database is 7.5G : query takes 12 min
250M edge, database is 19G : 35 min
500M edge, database is 38G : 12 hours with -XX:+UseG1GC 
1B edge, database is 76G : 51 hours without -XX:+UseG1GC

Futhermore for the 500 Million and 1 Billion test I can see that the bulk of the operations are system operations 60% versus user operation 40% (from top linux command). When I run the smaller test 100% of the operations are user operations.

Are the java GC improvement in the entreprise edition of Neo4j significant enough to bring the performance of the larger dataset query in the same proportion as the smaller one?
Is there something else I can do to improve the performance of larger dataset queries?

tks

I run all these test on a 32 core 244 RAM virtual server.

I also tried to increased the page cache size, but I didn't see an improvement.

Use case:
I am searching for pattern in the data, the query scan all the dataset to find 4 or 5 nodes that have a special pattern of relationships.

The query run in threads, so all 32 core are running simultaneously.

I tried to change:
- number of nodes per thread
- Heap size
- cache size
- GC options

But not much improvement.
Is this a Java restriction? 
thanks

Comment: Show your data model and use cases, and some sample code. Otherwise, there is not enough info.

Comment: See EXPLAIN, PROFILE to tune your queries (or create indexes if needed)

Comment: agree w/ cybersam. Also does hardware correspond to the dataset size ?

Comment: Can you add your query to the description, as well as its PROFILE plan (with all elements expanded)? Finding a better way to search for the pattern, and maybe even cache the results of the search for easier querying in the future, may help improve execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you try to configure the JVM heap, but have you done the same thing on the `page cache` ?

JVM's heap is used to store all the transaction stuff, and page cache to put in memory the graph data to avoid disk I/O.

I suggest you to take a look at this documentation (if it's not already done) page : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.2/performance/#memory-tuning

To have a java heap higher than 12Go can lead to some big GCs, and so to be less performant.

There are some improvements in EE, but for your specific case I don't think that the gap will be significative.

Finally, to have a query that needs all the data is a bad idea on every database system. I'm curious about the use-case. can you explain it ?

Like @Jerome said, you have to tune your query.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think tuning the query explain the scalability issue here, because the query is very efficient in smaller dataset ( up to 250 millions relations ) and exponentially slow when it get bigger. Java memory management has to play a role, but I cant find a way to go around it.

The query searches for triangle with increasing speed, and the max and min speed must be within a margin (50). The graph is simplified to have only one parameter on the relation (speed). Cypher query:
match (a)-[d]->(b)-[e]->(c)-[f]->(a) where d.speed<= e.speed AND e.speed <= f.speed AND (f.speed- d.speed) <= 50 return a, b, c.

Java Query run on each node in threads:

```
void findTriangleV1(Node n ){
    Iterable<Relationship> Level1 = n.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING);
    for( Relationship r1 : Level1 ) {
        if (r1.getEndNodeId() != n.getId()){
            Integer tsr1 = ( Integer )r1.getProperty( "speed" );
            Iterable<Relationship> Level2 = r1.getEndNode().getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING);
            for( Relationship r2 : Level2) {
                if (r1.getEndNodeId() != r2.getEndNodeId()){
                    Integer tsr2 = ( Integer )r2.getProperty( "speed" );                                
                    if ((tsr2 >= tsr1) && (tsr2 - tsr1 <= limit)){
                        Iterable<Relationship> Level3 = r2.getEndNode().getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING);
                        for( Relationship r3 : Level3) {
                            if (r3.getEndNodeId() == n.getId()){
                                Integer tsr3 = ( Integer )r3.getProperty( "speed" );
                                if ((tsr3 >= tsr2) && (tsr3 - tsr1 <= limit)){
                                    System.out.print( "\nV1 FOUND ONE ["+ n.getId() +" - "+ r1.getEndNodeId()+" - "+ r2.getEndNodeId()+"] & ");     
                                    System.out.print( "speed ["+ tsr1 +" - "+ tsr2+" - "+ tsr3+"] \n"); 
                                }                               
                            }
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```